# using StreamReader to read XElement leaves open elements

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, xelement

I have a `MemoryStream` that contains XML which I write to a file as follows:

```
var xml = XElement.Load(data.Content); // data.Content is of type `Stream`
var contentElement = new XElement("Content", xml);
var information = new XElement("TestInformation",
                      new XAttribute("Name", data.Descriptor.Name),
                      new XAttribute("Description", data.Descriptor.Description),
                      new XAttribute("Owner", data.Descriptor.Owner),
                      contentElement);
```

(`data` is an internal type - `DataObject` - that contains a `Stream` (called content) and a descriptor with metadata).

Later I try to read from this file as follows:

```
var returnValue = new DataObject();
var xElement = XElement.Load(fullPath);//the file path
returnValue.Descriptor = new Descriptor
                        {
                            Name = xElement.Attribute("Name").Value,
                            Description = xElement.Attribute("Description").Value,
                            Owner = xElement.Attribute("Owner").Value
                        };
returnValue.Content = GetContent(xElement.Element("Content"));
```

**GetContent method:**

```
private Stream GetContent(XElement element)
{
    var testElement = element.Elements().First();
    var contentStream = new MemoryStream();
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(contentStream);
    streamWriter.Write(testElement);
    contentStream.Position = 0;
    return contentStream;
}
```

When I try to read the stream as the internal type that I need, I get a `SerializationException` saying that some elements are not closed, and they really aren't - if I use a `StreamReader` to read this stream, it doesn't contain all the data that I saw in the `XElement`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `streamWriter.Flush()`?

Comment: Have you tried `testElement.Save(contentStream);`? `StreamWriter.Write(object)` is not really meant for writing XML, although it's a bit odd that using this omits some parts of the XML returned by `XElement.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I added the 'C#' tag since some of my previous questions were edited to add tags to their titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the use of `StreamWriter.Flush()`. This method causes the writer's buffer to be written to the stream.

Answer (score -1):

Write   `[Serializable]`
above class like this way

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass{
//TODO: Your code here 

}
```

try it and feed me back

Comment: XmlReaders/XmlSerializers don't require `Serializable` attribute. It is only needed for `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: The XML wasn't serialized. It was read from a file and this information was sent to de-serializtion.